# Rewrite engine. How to translate URL

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I am new to regular expressions and rewrite engine

I want to translate:
domain.com/type/id

on 
domain.com/index.php?type=type&id=id

I use
RewriteRule (\w+)/(\d+)$ ./index.php?id=$1&type=$2

I works almost fine and I am able to get two variables but website has a problem with including other files. My main URL is: http://domain.com/repos/site and after trying to type an URL like http://domain.com/repos/site/ee/9, firebug says:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://domain.com/repos/site/ee/lib/geoext/script/geoext.js"

It seems site takes "ee" as a part of ulr, not as a GET variable.

Comment: Quite normal as you rewrote your URL I'd say. Still, you could change the path you use to access the library. What path do you use at the moment?

Comment: Sure, I am able to change path to library, but is it really necessary? I will have to change all paths in Ajax request as well? Why it do not drops last part of URL (9)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will certainly have to change your paths. Paths behavior:
- href="mypath": will append "/mypath" to the URL from the current URL
- href="./mypath": same as before
- href="/mypath": will append mypath **to the root**. This is the behavior you want

Note: you can also use "../" to come back to the parent directory of where you are.

Comment: Thanks... What about directories? I used third option and I have domain.com/lib/... instead of domain.com/repos/site/lib/... Proviously I had "./mypath"

Comment: You'll have to add /repos/site I'm afraid.

Comment: hmmm... And I really do not want to do this because I don't know where this code will be pulled. Thanks anyway

Comment: Navigate backward using "../" cannot be a solution neither I guess?

Comment: Short term solution, I'am afraid:)